# Query only submitting once

Tags: php

For some reason this query will only submit if inside the table there isn't already a row that has the same reply_id.

Edit: How do I make it so it will just keep inputting the data? Would it have to do with duplicate key?
Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $blah = $_POST['id'];
    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['comment'])) {
            $errors[] = 'Error, try again!';
        }

        if (strlen($_POST['comment']) > 400) {
            $errors[] = 'Comment must be in a 10 to 400 characters range!';
        }

        if (empty($errors)) {
            $q2 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO reply VALUES($blah, _comment, now(), '$id')");
            header("Location: topic.php?id=$blah");
        } else {
            echo 'You have ' . (count($errors) + 1) . ' errors in your form:<br />';
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo $error . '<br />';
            }
            echo '<a href="new_topic.php">Try again</a>';
        }
    }
```

Form:

```
<form action="topic.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="comment" class="field span6" rows="3"
              placeholder="Content..."></textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Reply"/></div>
</form>
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Sorry about that @wumm, I updated my post. I guess I was sorta slow there

Comment: `on duplicate key update` this?

Comment: do you want duplicate ids in your table?

Comment: Yes I tried changing the query to this: $q2 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO reply VALUES($blah, \"$comment\", now(), '$id') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"); Although that didnt work

Comment: Yes @vaibhavmande, that is what I want to do. :) Any ideas?

Comment: BTW It's not very clever to name a variable $blah. Could you show use your table structure?

Comment: Since you didn't post your table's structure as I requested [in this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332321/having-trouble-with-post-and-get#comment28638453_19332321), and since you apparently moved foward, can I ask again? _Please_ post your table structure?

Comment: And another question: Where does `$id` take a value?

Comment: Sorry, @geomagas I didn't see that comment earlier. I thought people gave up :/ But yes its fixed now :) There just 1 problem still thats probably a quick fix :) Read below.

Comment: $id = $_SESSION['id']

Comment: Do you _really_ think that spreading comments and links to images all over and then telling people to "Read Below" is the best way to help us _help you_? Update your question and keep it consistent so that other people visiting your topic in need for assistance will have a clear picture of how _your_ issue was resolved.

Comment: Im actually on my phone at the moment and can't edit, I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, if you want duplicate entries in your code.

Remove `header("Location: topic.php?id=$blah");` from your code.
The page submit to the same page again resulting in the execution of query each time you submit.

Related to the question where multiple comments arent displaying

```
$res2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2) /* will return only one row */
```

you will have to loop through all the results, use

```
while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {

echo $res2['reply_content'] /*will print each content*/

}
```

Comment: is the col you are inserting `$id` into primary key? If thats the case follow what geomagas said.

Comment: I dropped the table, remade it and now it works perfectly. One problem, if I want to echo the comments like I have with my other script, how would I make it echo even if reply_id is duplicated. How could I make it just select all of them no matter how many there are?

Comment: just select all comments, dont put a `WHERE` condition for id

Comment: Here check out these two images. Not sure why but it only displays 1 comment, not all. http://gyazo.com/ca8233ce1d0fbc61faaf3464e548a365.png

http://gyazo.com/e776a247c1a9a2f7fbf51fa19b4c02e7.png

Answer (score 0):

If `reply_id` is the primary key of your table, there's no way to insert duplicates.

If you *do* want duplicate `reply_id`s, alter (or drop) the primary key.